# How do I add a #.## value to a textbox that already has another ##.## value in it only if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have been trying to figure out how to make it so that if a specific checkbox is checked, the total amount in a textbox gets 50.00 added to it when the submit button is clicked, before it submits the form. In fact, it would be better to have the update happen as soon as the checkbox is checked.

Here's what i tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function toggle(){
var indoorCamping = 50.00;
var total = 0.00;
if(document.getElementByName('fifty').is(':checked')){
total = (indoorCamping + document.getElementsByName('Amount').value);
document.getElementsByName('Amount').value = total;
}

else{
return;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<input type="checkbox" name="fifty" value="indoor"/>

<label for="Amount">Amount <span class="req">*</span> <span 

id="constraint-300-label"></span></label><br />
                <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="Amount" name="Amount" />

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="toggle()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a text-input is always text (a string) initially. This value needs to be explicitly converted to a number before adding to it, otherwise it concatenates the text. So "20" would become "5020".

Borrowing mohkhan's code:

```
<script>
function toggle(checkbox){
    var indoorCamping = 50.00;
    var total = 0.00;
    if(checkbox.checked){
        total = (indoorCamping + document.getElementById('Amount').value * 1);
        document.getElementById('Amount').value = total;
    }
}
</script>
```

I've multipled by 1 which is one way to convert "20" to a number. `Number(x)`, `parseInt(x)` and `parseFloat(x)` are other ways.

I would prefer to use an object variable though, `amt`:

```
<script>
function toggle(checkbox) {
    var indoorCamping = 50.00;
    var total = 0.00;
    var amt = null;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        amt = document.getElementById('Amount');
        total = (indoorCamping + amt.value * 1);
        amt.value = total;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Seems a shame, though, to be charged an extra 50 quid just for staying indoors :)

Comment: Haha. hey i'm just doing what the client is asking. Your code works perfect, but i was wondering if you could help me with one tiny teeny thing more. Right now if the original value in the text box is say 250.00, when i check the box it adds 50.00 but updates the textbox value to 300 not 300.00. What would be the best way to fix that?

Comment: Use `amt.value = total.toFixed(2);`

Comment: Genius! Ok but one extra thing and this should be the last one. The value for the "Amount" textbox will be increasing by $5 every month. There must be a way to have that change automatically say the 1st of every month right? I am also concerned that this page might cache on some browsers and that someone who might have visited the page 2 months prior will see the old price as opposed to the updated one. I've read that the no-cache meta tag doesn't work in all browsers. What would be your advice to tackle that?

Comment: Thank you. You do realise, though, that all this JavaScript can be interfered with by the user? It really requires server-side scripting. Anyway, You can use `new Date()` to obtain today's date and then `getDate()` to discover if it is the 1st. But where would you store what the *current value* is, so that you could increase it? You could, I suppose, assume the value of 50 starting at a specific date, then add 5 * the number of months since that date.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the no-cache business because, if you continue with JavaScript, the entire script can be interfered with by the user anyway. (You might investigate caching though, for your own education.)

Comment: Ok, i promise this is the last question... for a couple of days. I just realized that the code doesn't take care of the situation when the user might check it, change his mind and uncheck it.

Comment: I tried writing an else-if statement:
else if(!checkbox.checked){
        total = (amt.value * 1.00 - indoorCamping);
        amt.value = total.toFixed(2);
    }

Comment: I guessed this straight-away based on the name of your function `toggle()` :) That code looks like it should work check your browser's console for errors. Or add your updated code to your original question - please don't delete the original question or code!! Add it at the bottom.

Comment: never mind, i figured it out. 'amt' was still pointing to null because it had skipped the first if statement. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Add the click event on the checkbox then. Like this...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fifty" value="indoor" onclick="toggle(this);"/>
```

And then in your script...

```
<script>
function toggle(checkbox){
var indoorCamping = 50.00;
var total = 0.00;
if(checkbox.checked){
    total = (indoorCamping + document.getElementById('Amount').value);
    document.getElementById('Amount').value = total;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` expects to return a collection, so it would be better to use `getElementsByName('Amount')[0]` or, even better, use the id.

Comment: thank you mohkhan, i had actually tried something like this before with no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to describe the problem. What happens? Are there errors in your browser's console?

Comment: thank you andy, i didn't know what the problem was, it just didn't do anything when i clicked the checkbox.